# Convex combination of measures define a new probability measure, $a\mathbb{P}+b\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Show that if $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are two probability measures defined on the same (countable) sample space, then $a\mathbb{P} + b\mathbb{Q}$ is also a probability measure for any two nonnegative numbers $a$ and $b$ satisfying $a + b = 1$.

I understand what I have to do but mathematically I don't know how to prove this

Answer (score 2):

You need to show that $\mathbb{P}^*=a\mathbb{P}+b\mathbb{Q}$ satisfies the probability measure definition. Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space, $\mathbb{P}^*$ is a measure onto it if it satisfies the following conditions,

1. $\mathbb{P}^*:\mathcal{F}\to[0,1]$
2. $\mathbb{P}^*$ is $\sigma$-aditive: If $(A_k)_{k\geq 1}$ is a sequence of disjoint sets in $\mathcal{F}$ then $$\mathbb{P}^*(\bigcup_{k\geq1}A_k)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\mathbb{P}^*(A_k)$$
3. $\mathbb{P}^*(\Omega)=1$

Comment: 3 is easiest and once you understand that, 1 and 2 are also easy

Comment: im struggling to understand why 3 holds

Comment: @jamessmithh2002 A tip: We know that the above hold for $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ isolated, try working with that a little bit.